# How to cover all hosts with Ansible pull method?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-pull

I know that it is possible to turn Ansible into pull architecture: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html

What I am having trouble is that it seems Ansible still wants to manage inventory.  So using the script to pull the repository:

```
ansible-pull -U <repository> [options] [<playbook.yml>]
```

I get following warning:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: XYZA
```

and when running actual playbook I get this message:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

As by default Ansible will search for hosts in `/etc/ansible/hosts` file. But now that it is pulling, it should not care about hosts in my opinion. I know I could also specify hosts with `-i` parameter as array, for example:

```
ansible-pull -U git@github.com/somerepo -i localhost, playbook.yml
```

But in my case there are a lot of hosts and I just want to run the playbook against all of them that are pulling from that repository. Is there any way to do that, or do I need dynamically specify for each host separate script/inventory?

EDIT: I have also tried `-i all` or `-i all,` but does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was just a warning, not an error, so Ansible pull should still run. Running it with the inventory `localhost` does the trick:
`ansible-pull -U git@github.com/somerepo -i localhost, playbook.yml`

Comment: Also discussed in YouTube video "Using Ansible to automate your Laptop and Desktop configs!" at 42:03 (or, more generally, from 31:16 to 42:33) (see: https://youtu.be/gIDywsGBqf4?t=2523)